# Remove Extra Spaces between title and doughnut chart and legend in flutter

Tags: flutter, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I am using syncfusion circular chart in which i have set doughnut chart type which give me extra spaces between title, chart and legends. how to reduce the extra spaces between them?

[image]

here is code which set these

```
      Expanded(
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), // if you need this
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              child: Container(
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-15.0, 0.0, 00.0),
                child: SfCircularChart(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0,horizontal: 12.0),
                  title: ChartTitle(
                    text: 'Today\'s Employee\'s Attendance',
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff15728a),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 8.0),
                  ),
                  tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
                  legend: Legend(
                      position: LegendPosition.bottom,
                      isVisible: true,
                      isResponsive:true,
                      overflowMode: LegendItemOverflowMode.wrap),
                  series: <CircularSeries>[
                    DoughnutSeries<AttendanceData, String>(

                      dataSource: attendance,
                      pointColorMapper:(AttendanceData data,_)=>data.colors,
                      xValueMapper: (AttendanceData data, _) =>
                      data.status,
                      yValueMapper: (AttendanceData data, _) =>
                      data.value,
                      dataLabelSettings:
                      DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
                      enableTooltip: true,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Your requirement to get rid of empty space between the legend and the chart can be achieved by using [centerY](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/SfCircularChart/centerY.html) property which is used to position the chart vertically. Similarly, you can move and place them horizontally at the required place using the [centerX](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/SfCircularChart/centerX.html) property. We have attached the screenshot for your reference and please make use of it.

Code snippet

```
SfCircularChart( centerY: '750', )
```

Screenshot

[image]

You can also contact us through our support [forums](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums), [Direct-Trac](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents), or [feedback portal](https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback) if you need any further assistance. We are always happy to assist you!

Comment: i tried this solution  it remove distance at one side as like it remove space from legend but increase space from chart tile . it cant shrink that both chart title and legend get equal space and chart became in center

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin property of SfCircularChart to get rid of the distance.
Code Snippet:

`margin: EdgeInsets.zero,`